# Using instruments on my ios 5.0.1 iphone4 phone makes it reboot right away

Tags: ios, ios5, instruments

I'd like to understand why, and find a solution obviously. I can't figure it out, given the console disappears as soon as the device reboots and is then reset when it comes back from the reboot. So I don't have any clue of what's going on there.

iphone4, ios 5.0.1 installed, jailbroken when the latest redsnow & untethered JB. I tried in safe mode, same thing.

I noticed that everytime I connect the phone osx mounts a developerdiskimage volume while xcode is displaying "checking DDI symbols", and after that then the phone is considered valid for dev by xcode. After the phone just rebooted, it's shown as invalid for development in xcode, until I unplug / replug it. I don't think I ever noticed that before, could it be related?

Comment: Obviously it has something to do with the jailbreak. Therefore there's not much I can do but wait for an update.

Answer (score 0):

With the new ios 5.1.1 jailbreak out. You might want to revisit it again. I had a similar problem where I could mesure leaks but trying to mesure CoreAnimation or anything else would restart the device.